# How to store multiple selected values of radio as well as checkboxes in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store multiple selected values of radio buttons as well as checkboxes into MySQL database using PHP. Please let me know the name and value to be entered in input button and how to pass it in a Mysql query ?

**Example 1(Radio Buttons):**

Answer 1  Answer 2  Answer 2 
Answer 3   Answer 4  Any other reasons, Please specify

**Example 2 (Check boxes)**

Answer 1

Answer 2

Answer 3

Answer 4, Pls specify

Answer 5

Answer 6

None

Comment: Nice homework you have

Comment: your checkbox example is bizarre, you can select a `None`answer and `Answer1`

Answer (score 4):

Radio group can only have one item selected. Check-box you can store value for more than one option.

What I am providing is just an example and not a working code. You need to refer and do needful as per your requirement.

*First populate input fields with below example code*

**Radio Group**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="answer1">
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="answer2">
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="answer3">
```

**Checkbox Group**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_group[]" value="answer1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_group[]" value="answer2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_group[]" value="answer3">
```

Now create a table into your database something similar as below

**Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `your_table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `radio_group` enum('answer1','answer2','answer3') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'answer2',  // for radio button
  `checkbox_group` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  // for checkbox serialized data
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are many ways to insert data into the table. Find few options in below example

**Example 1**

```
$my_radio_value = $_POST['radio_group'];
$my_checkbox_values = $_POST['checkbox_group'];
$checkbox_result = serialize($my_checkbox_values);

// now store $my_radio_value and $checkbox_result in table by running query
INSERT INTO `your_table_name` (radio_group, checkbox_group) VALUES ($my_radio_value, $checkbox_result);
```

**Example 2**

You also can use `json` instead of `serialize`

```
$my_radio_value = $_POST['radio_group'];
$my_checkbox_values = $_POST['checkbox_group'];
$checkbox_result = json_encode($my_checkbox_values);

// now store $my_radio_value and $checkbox_result in table by running query
INSERT INTO `your_table_name` (radio_group, checkbox_group) VALUES ($my_radio_value, $checkbox_result);
```

**Example 3**

But it is not good idea to use `$_POST` directly. You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `filter_input()`. Personally I prefer to use `filter_input()`

```
// using mysql_real_escape_string()
$my_radio_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['radio_group']);
$my_checkbox_values = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['checkbox_group']);

// using filter_input()
$my_radio_value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'radio_group');
$my_checkbox_values = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox_group');


// serialize output for checkbox
$checkbox_result = serialize($my_checkbox_values);

// json output for checkbox
$checkbox_result = json_encode($my_checkbox_values);

// now store $my_radio_value and $checkbox_result in table by running query
INSERT INTO `your_table_name` (radio_group, checkbox_group) VALUES ($my_radio_value, $checkbox_result);
```

I hope this will help you :)